# ¿Cómo funciona el agregado "... out", al traducir al español?

Tags: inglés

Estoy viendo un [video en YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ViQH9A9SWOA) que trata sobre Alf Zumpano, un zapatero que cuenta su historia reparando zapatos en la ciudad en la que se ubica.

En el segundo 20 de video dice:

> Everybody has shoes, everybody wears shoes, everybody wears **out** shoes.

Inmediatamente me pregunto: ¿qué información agrega la última oración, a la que se añade "*out*"? Es como si quisiera decir: todo el mundo tiene zapatos, todo el mundo usa, todo el mundo sale con zapatos (a la calle, lugares de trabajo, etc., infiriendo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to *wear* es *vestir* o *calzar*. *wear out* es un verbo que quiere decir *gastar* ou *desgastar*. Y no se aplica solo a los zapatos.

Todo el mundo desgasta zapatos. Everyone wears out shoes.

Está en los diccionários monolingües. Se llama un verbo con/de dos palabras (two-word verb o phrasal verb).